# Spring Integration - JPA inbound channel adapter, splitter, service activator concurrent unit of work

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I have a pretty simple Spring integration pipeline setup

1. Loads N-times Assets having status X, with JPA, into a channel
2. Splits each JPA entity onto a new channel
3. Processes JPA entity, using a service activator, finally updating the entity's status to Y

The synchronous nature of this pipeline means that the JPA inbound channel adapter only fires once all the messages in the previous inbound channel adapter, and in turn split channel have been processed, and sent to the `nullChannel`

This works very well, but is inefficient.

The service activator does a few things, one of them being that it calls an external REST API, and then updates the status of the Asset, so it will be excluded from #1.

The problem here is the the service activator takes about 1 second to process a single message (most of this time is the call to the REST API), and as such, a queue of 250 JPA entities could take 250 seconds to process.

If we call the REST API concurrently, say 5 times, it would still take 1 second.

So, I am wondering if there is a simple alteration that we can make to our pipeline, maybe adding an `Aggregator` and a `Task Executor`, that will allow the entire pipeline to run as a synchronous "Unit Of Work", but allow the `Service Activator` to process concurrently.

This is the integration configuration

```
<channel id="newAssetChannel" />
<channel id="splitAssetChannel" />

<int-jpa:inbound-channel-adapter
        id="newAssetChannelAdapter"
        channel="newAssetChannel"
        entity-manager-factory="entityManagerFactory" 
        entity-class="com.foo.domain.Asset" 
        jpa-query="select a from Asset a where (a.status = 'NEW' or a.status = 'UPDATED') and a.health = 'OK' ORDER BY a.priority DESC, a.updatedDate ASC"
        max-results="250">
    <poller fixed-rate="5000" max-messages-per-poll="1" />
</int-jpa:inbound-channel-adapter>

<splitter expression="payload"
    input-channel="newAssetChannel"
    output-channel="splitNewAssetChannel" />

<service-activator
    id="newAssetServiceActivator"
    input-channel="splitNewAssetChannel"
    output-channel="nullChannel"
    ref="assetProcessor"
    method="processNew" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the `aggregator` is really the right way to go for waiting for all replies, but together with the `ExecutorChannel` after `splitter` you free poller's hands anyway. So, you should have some barrier before-after parallel splitting-aggregation.

You can do that with the `<gateway>`:

```
<gateway id="gateway" default-request-channel="splitterChannel"/>

<service-activator id="gatewayTestService" input-channel="newAssetChannel" output-channel="saveRowsChannel" ref="gateway"/>
```

The splitter's `output-channel` must be `ExecutorChannel`. The `newAssetServiceActivator` must output to the `aggregator`. The aggregator doesn't have an `output-channel` meaning the reply to that `gateway`.

Comment: This put me on the right path, and definitely lead to me having a better understanding of Spring Integration in general. Full updated config here (comments appreciated in the gist if I have done something that could be improved) - gist.github.com/shainegordon/66da307b2e89f69e549b675ffbfd363‌​e